# var property vs this.property in object constructor in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, constructor

Is there any difference between "this.property" vs "var property" inside object constructor?

example:

```
var person = function(){
    var age;
    this.firstName;        
}
```

Comment: Yes, there is difference. One is the local variable, another is the object property.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. For example, if you instantiate a new `person` like so:

```
var p = new person();
```

You will be able to access the `firstName` variable from outside, which becomes a property of the new object:

```
console.log(p.firstName); // whatever you assigned it to
```

But not the `age` variable, whose scope is limited to inside the function body:

```
console.log(p.age); // undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.property` returns the property of the calling object. In this case, the one calling `person()` function.

`var property` just define a variable whose scope is the function `person()`